# If $0\leq X \leq \text{Id}$ and $0\leq A$, then $XAX \leq A$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-semidefinite, linear-matrix-inequality

Let $X,A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and suppose
$$ 0 \leq X \leq \text{Id}, \quad 0\leq A, $$
where $\text{Id}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ denotes the identity matrix. Is it true that
$$ XAX \leq A, $$
or can you give a counterexample? For a proof I would imagine $0\leq \text{Id} - X$ is important, however, I have not been able to show the inequality.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what $\leq$ means? Are $X$ and $A$ Hermitian?

Comment: @BartMichels Sure! $0\leq X$ means $X$ is positive-semidefinite, which in turn implies $X$ and $A$ are Hermitian. Also, $X\leq \text{Id}$ means $\text{Id}-X$ is positive semi-definite

Comment: Thanks! Maybe it helps to diagonalize $X$, so that it is diagonal with real entries between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here seems to be a counterexample.
Let
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\
X=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have $0\leq A$, $0\leq X\leq Id$, $XAX=X$, and
$$
B=A-XAX=A-X=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Matrix $B$ is not positive definite matrix.